How to use absolute paths and baseUrl with typescript compiler
When bundling package with tsc I get wrong output.
Here is my project directory structure:
common
└── index.ts
types
├── action.ts
├── index.ts
└── request.ts
utils
├── event.ts
├── index.ts
├── request.ts
└── response.ts
package.json 
tsconfig.json

Content of my tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  }
}

As you can see I've enabled baseUrl: '.'.
Content of common/index.ts:
import { ErrorPayload } from 'types'
import { responseActionMaker } from 'utils'

export class ResRaiseError implements ErrorPayload {
  code: string
  message?: Record<string, any>
  stack?: string
}

export const resRaiseError = responseActionMaker<ResRaiseError>()

As you can see, I'm using absolute paths and when compiling the package, tsc doesn't raise an error because it can finds packages using baseUrl: '.'. The problem is that it produces wrong output in 'dist/common/index.js':
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.resRaiseError = exports.ResRaiseError = void 0;
const utils_1 = require("utils");
class ResRaiseError {
}
exports.ResRaiseError = ResRaiseError;
exports.resRaiseError = (0, utils_1.responseActionMaker)();
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map

It can't find 'utils' and hence projects which using this package, couldn't have any typing too because dist/common/index.d.ts has wrong paths for imports also.
Currently I'm forced to use related paths always:
import { ErrorPayload } from '../types'
import { responseActionMaker } from '../utils'

export class ResRaiseError implements ErrorPayload {
  code: string
  message?: Record<string, any>
  stack?: string
}

export const resRaiseError = responseActionMaker<ResRaiseError>()


Questions: How make tsc convert absolute paths to suitable relative paths automatically when building/compiling package?
I expect tsc to convert import {anything} from 'utils'into import {anything} from '../utils'


Install tsc-alias as a dev dependency:



"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc && tsc-alias"
}




In tsconfig.json, add the paths option:



"paths": {
    "common/*": ["common/*"],
    "types/*": ["types/*"],
    "utils/*": ["utils/*"]
  }




Update your package.json build script:



"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc && tsc-alias"
}



Upon running npm run build, it will first compile your TypeScript files with tsc, and then tsc-alias will post-process the compiled files to convert the absolute paths to relative paths.
